# How to install pthreads and Zend gaurd loader together

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, php-extension

I am using PHP 5.4.36 (cli) in my cPanel server . When I am installing pthreads using pecl its throwing following errors.

> checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled

So I went ahead and enabled ZTS

```
echo -enable-maintainer-zts >> /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5
```

After the installation Zendguard loader is not working.

> [~]# php -v

Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-6.0.0/php-5.4.x/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-6.0.0/php-5.4.x/ZendGuardLoader.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals
PHP 5.4.36 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2015 11:15:57)

Kindly help anyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

cPanel do not ship the ZTS-enabled versions of the pre-compiled modules for Zend Guard Loader which means that Zend Guard loader will fail when trying to use --enable-maintainer-zts on a system. As such, that setting cannot be used when using the EasyApache or /scripts/phpextensionsmgr installations (the cPanel ones) for the pre-compiled Zend Guard Loader which cPanel provide.